# Vue reactivity is always one step behind

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2

I have the following setup:
A type `StringMap` which I want to work like Map<> but since I'm using vue2, Map<> reactivity is not possible and I've tried to do it myself via an Array:

```
import Vue from "vue";

export default class StringMap {

    entries: Array<[string, number]>;

    constructor(data?: Record<string, number>) {
        Vue.set(this, "entries", data ? Object.keys(data).map((key) => [key, data[key]]) : []);
    }

    get(key: string): number {
        return this.entries.find((e) => e[0] === key)?.[1];
    }

    set(key: string, value: number): this {
        const entry = this.entries.find((e) => e[0] === key);
        if (entry) {
            Vue.set(entry, 1, value);
        }
        else {
            this.entries.push([key, value]);
        }
        return this;
    }

    has(key: string): boolean {
        return this.entries.some((e, idx, arr) => e[0] === key);
    }

    delete(key: string): boolean {
        const idx = this.entries.findIndex((e, idx, obj) => e[0] === key);
        if (idx != -1) {
            this.entries.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        return idx != -1;
    }

    clear(): void {
        Vue.set(this, "entries", []);
    }
}
```

In my Vue-Template, I have an input-field that listens to the @change method and calls calculateTotals()

```
<input :id="'viewModel.phasenChangeRequests[0].ppmProjektPhaseResource[' + index +'].personalInternPlanFach_PT'"
                                       v-model="viewModel.phasenChangeRequests[0].ppmProjektPhaseResource[index].personalInternPlanFach_PT"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       asp-horizontal="true"
                                       @change="calculateTotals('totalPersonalInternPlanFach_PT')"/>
```

And the `calculateTotals` is just looping over the data and summing the fields:

```
calculateTotals(key: string = null) {
        if (this.type === "PhasenCrs") {
            let totalPersonalInternPlanFachPt = 0;

            for (let year = this.startyear; year < this.startyear + 5; year++) {
                const phasen = this.viewModel.phasenChangeRequests;
                phasen.forEach((phase) => {
                    var ressourcenOfYear = phase.ppmProjektPhaseResource.filter(x => x.resourceYear === year)[0];
                    totalPersonalInternPlanFachPt += parseFloat(ressourcenOfYear.personalInternPlanFach_PT);
                });
            }

            if (key === null) {
                console.log(`Key 'totalPersonalInternPlanFach_PT' doesn't exist yet, set it to: ${totalPersonalInternPlanFachPt}`);
                this.totals2.set("totalPersonalInternPlanFach_PT", totalPersonalInternPlanFachPt);
            } else {
                switch (key) {
                    case 'totalPersonalInternPlanFach_PT':
                    {
                        console.log(`set totalPersonalInternPlanFach_PT: ${totalPersonalInternPlanFachPt}`);
                        this.totals2.set("totalPersonalInternPlanFach_PT", totalPersonalInternPlanFachPt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`totals2` is a StringMap that is initialized in the created() method:

```
totals2: StringMap;

async created() {
        this.startyear = parseInt(moment(this.startdate, "DD.MM.YYYY").format("YYYY"));
        this.projekt = JSON.parse(this.projektjson);
        this.totals2 = new StringMap();

        await Axios.get(this.url)
            .then(res => {
                this.viewModel = res.data;
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.calculateTotals();
            });
    }
```

When I run it, it initially looks like this:
[image]

So as you can see, all fields for each year are summed correctly.
When I now change the value of 2021, the following happens:
[image]

But in the console, I can see that the total was calculated correctly:
[image]

When I now change the value back to the initial value, it shows this:
[image]
[image]

So that the previous change is now reflected in the total field but the console is showing the correct result again.

It seems that the value in the view is always one tick behind the real value...

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want keyup, not change. I believe change is triggered when you tab or click outside the input after changing. But you want it to immediately calculate the value.

Comment: @PeterKrebs thank you, but it's the same effect with `@keyup` unfortunately

Comment: Okay that might indeed be a problem then. So try this: `Vue.set(this, 'totals2',this.totals2.set("totalPersonalInternPlanFach_PT", totalPersonalInternPlanFachPt));`. If that fails, does it work with `this.$forceUpdate();` at the end of the function? Also the `string` parameter of `calculateTotals` is never used - why not have a `computed` value then?

Comment: the `Vue.set(...)` did not work unfortunately but the `this.$forceUpdate();` does... with this the value in the UI is reflected correctly... hmm

Comment: You are rendering `<input>` elements with `v-for` without using `:key` ....that is the [problem](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State)

Comment: @MichalLevý thank you, I've added the `:key` binding, but without the `this.$forceUpdate();`, the frontend is still one change behind